# SQL IF ELSE Statement During SELECT?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need help... the following query gives an error when trying to use IF Else.
The SERIAL_NUMBER field has the two digit year in it and I want to extract it and display it as a 4 digit year in it's own field.

```
SELECT 
   [START_TIMESTAMP]
  ,[END_TIMESTAMP]
  ,[SERIAL_NUMBER]
  ,[MODEL]
  ,[TESTING_ACTION_RESULT]
  ,[FAILED_STEP]
  ,[DISPOSITION]
  ,[TesterId]
  ,[Location]
  ,[Customer]
  ,IF CAST(substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2)AS INT)>90
    '19'+substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2) AS MFG_YYYY
   ELSE
    '20'+substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2) AS MFG_YYYY
FROM [DATABASE_1].[dbo].[TBL_Unit_Test]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an IF in a SELECT statement, instead you will use a [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

```
SELECT 
   [START_TIMESTAMP]
  ,[END_TIMESTAMP]
  ,[SERIAL_NUMBER]
  ,[MODEL]
  ,[TESTING_ACTION_RESULT]
  ,[FAILED_STEP]
  ,[DISPOSITION]
  ,[TesterId]
  ,[Location]
  ,[Customer]
  ,case 
    when CAST(substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2)AS INT)>90
    then '19'+substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2)
    else '20'+substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2) end AS MFG_YYYY
FROM [DATABASE_1].[dbo].[TBL_Unit_Test]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CASE expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), like

```
SELECT 
   [START_TIMESTAMP]
  ,[END_TIMESTAMP]
  ,[SERIAL_NUMBER]
  ,[MODEL]
  ,[TESTING_ACTION_RESULT]
  ,[FAILED_STEP]
  ,[DISPOSITION]
  ,[TesterId]
  ,[Location]
  ,[Customer]
  , MFG_YYYY =
   CASE 
    WHEN CAST(substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2)AS INT)>90 
       THEN '19'+substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2)
    ELSE '20'+substring([SERIAL_NUMBER],3,2)
   END
FROM [DATABASE_1].[dbo].[TBL_Unit_Test]
GO
```